# While loop to solve a diffusion problem

Tags: linear-algebra, procedural-programming

Crossposted at *Wolfram Community:* https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2506329

I am trying to use a While loop to solve for a diffusion problem using the power iteration method. The code is supposed to loop through three equations (flux, source, and k) until the fluxdiff > 0.0001. I am trying get this code to plot the flux and print a table of the flux, k, source, and fluxdiff. Right now the code does not produce any outputs and I am not sure where the problem(s) is/are. If there's a way to use a "Table" to solve this problem, I am willing to try it.

````
sigmaa = .1532;
\[Nu]sigmaf = .1570;
d = 1/(3 (.0362));

nodes3 = 4;
r1 = 1;
dr1 = r1/nodes3



a = 
  Table[If[i == j, sigmaa*i*dr1*dr1 + (2 i dr1 d)/dr1, 
    If[i - j == 1, -d/dr1 (i*dr1 - dr1/2), 
     If[i - j == -1, -d/dr1 (i*dr1 + dr1/2), 0]]], {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 
    3}];
anew = ReplacePart[a, {1, 1} -> d/2 + sigmaa dr1^2/8]


b = Table[If[i == 1, \[Nu]sigmaf/2, \[Nu]sigmaf], {i, 1, nodes3}, {j, 1}]

flux = {{1}, {1}, {1}, {1}};
k = 1.0000;
source = b flux

fluxdiff = 1;
iteration = 0;

oldflux = flux;
oldk = k;
oldsource = source;

While[fluxdiff > 0.0001,
 Print[iteration, flux, source, k, fluxdiff];
 
 oldflux = flux;
 oldk = k;
 oldsource = source;
 iteration = iteration + 1;
 
 flux = 1/oldk LinearSolve[a, oldsource];
 source = b flux;
 k = oldk Total[source]/Total[oldsource];
 
 fluxdiff = 0;
 fluxdiff = Sqrt[fluxdiff + (Total[flux] - Total[oldflux])^2];
 
 
 ]
```
````

Comment: At a minimum, `flux` and `source` are never initialized

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the initialization when I copied the code.  It is not working even with the initialization.

Comment: Your `fluxdiff` starts off as a scalar and gets converted to a `List` of length 1. Since a `List` cannot be greater than a scalar, the procedure terminates. Check your code for why you are generating extraneous `List` brackets.

Comment: Thanks for that tip.  I have made `fluxdiff` a scalar, but the loop still isn't executing.

Comment: Continuation from above - 
The fluxdiff at the end of the `While` is now `fluxdiff=Sqrt[fluxdiff + (Total[flux] - Total[oldflux])^2]`.  I have updated the code in the original comment, any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: `fluxdiff` is still a list at the end of the `While`. Change the last line of the `While` to `Print@StringForm["fluxdiff = ``", 
  fluxdiff = Sqrt[fluxdiff + (Total[flux] - Total[oldflux])^2]]` to see the value of `fluxdiff` at exit.